# How to use Form keys in php

Tags: php, forms

In my page i want to use form keys for submission of forms. But i dont know how to use the formkeys in php. Cant get clear idea about the uses of form keys when i searched for that. How to achieve this. Where can i see the demo for this form keys in php. Thanks in advance

Comment: They cant answer my question so they closed my questions. They have no idea about my question. They couldn't understand my simple question so they closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" name="text"/>`

$name = $_POST['text'];

`$_POST` is an array which contains form values. use input name (text in this case)